# How can I resolve a main class error from cmd

Tags: java, cmd

I wrote a simple java program that will require external jar file to compile and run. I've successfully compiled the .java file but i keep getting "Error: could not find or load main class 'Simple' " whenever i try to run the .class file using java command

Comment: show your code and how you call it. Also read [ask].

Comment: Provide the code and error you are getting.

Comment: Might be you forget to set path.

Comment: Well... you want us to debug your code, but you don't show it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing your class itself in classpath, use `.` while running your code

On windows:

```
java -classpath external.jar;. MyClass
```

On linux:

```
java -classpath external.jar:. MyClass
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-classpath` argument of javac.

`javac -classpath path/to/library1.jar MyClass.java`

Comment: Yeah, I've compiled it with such command but here is the command i used to run it "java -classpath external.jar MyClass"

Comment: You need to compile with javac, not with java

Comment: Also, I think you need to put .java after MyClass. Try "javac -classpath external.jar MyClass.java"

Comment: I did it and it compiles successfully using the command you provided. It generated a .class file as expected

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your CLASSPATH environment variable. refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)
 link for more information on CLASSPATH variable.